# Strange Error with Loading a View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, controller, ios7

I'm updating my application for iOS 7. I have a navigation controller with its root view controller as a UITableView. When I tap a row it should open up a nib file specific to the row tapped that I made. The way I've set it up is the following:

```
#import "myTableView.h"
#import "wantedNibFile.h"

@implementation myTableView

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)\
indexPath

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *rowValue = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

if ([rowValue isEqualToString:@"cell text" ]) {

wantedNibFile *thing = [[wantedNibFile alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:thing animated:YES];

}
```

When I run this program Xcode takes me to the text below. If it's contained by to asterisks, that means the debugger highlighted it in red.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  **"_OBJC_CLASS_$wantedNibFile", referenced from:**
      objc-class-ref in myTableView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is 'wantedNibFile'? A class or a Nib? Inherited from UIViewController?!? Nobody can tell by your code, because you don't follow the common naming conventions. Consider reading Apple's Code Naming basics: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH

Answer (score 0):

Your file wantedNibFile.m is not added to target for some reason. To fix it just choose it in navitator and set Target Membership on the right of screen to proper target.